# Resolution of baseUrl changes after Spring Upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an application that uses Spring Cloud Gateway, and as part of that application we have also added Spring Security so that unsecured requests will be redirected to an OAuth2 authorization server.  We were using Spring Boot 2.3.12.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR1.  We configured the Spring Security OAuth2 components to provide a redirect_uri value as part of the call authorize call.  This worked fine, and you can see a sample of the uri value which works.

[image]

In order to derive this value, the String passed into the Spring Security code uses the variable {baseUrl}
[image]

We are in the process of upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.10 and Spring Cloud 2021.0.6.  Now, when we log in, though, the login fails because the redirect_uri is not known (the OAuth2 provider we use will knock back any requests with any unknown redirect_uri values).  When I look at what is being passed to the authorize call, the value in request_uri is, indeed, incorrect.

[image]

It looks like when the baseUri variable is resolved, it is now including the port.

Is there any details for how this value is populated?  Or if there are other values that will allow me to get the redirect_uri defined correctly?

Comment: It looks like baseUrl is a variable defined by Spring Security, and defaults to {baseScheme}://{baseHost}{basePort}{basePath}  So it seems like basePort evaluation has changed... reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html#oauth2Client-auth-code-redirect-uri

Comment: When I compare DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.expandRedirectUri between the two Spring Security versions (before, 5.3.9, after 5.7.7), the methods look pretty much the same.  So unless the ServerHttpRequest is different, I'm struggling to find a cause here.

Comment: The best I can come up with... HTTPS is correctly being used because in the cloud this application is executing behind a gateway.  But, where the application is running behind that gateway, HTTP, not HTTPS, is being used (the communication between the gateway and application is HTTP).  Maybe that port is being provided as part of the Request URI in the new version?  I don't know.  Best I've got is to change the template to stop using baseUrl and build it from the components to ensure the port is not included.